# nrf24L01 on a raspberry using nrf24L01_plus

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I'm pretty new on the Raspberry Pi and I would like to use a [nrf24L01](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B01CYDXAI4/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1) transceiver between two Raspberry Pis and maybe later between a Raspberry Pis and an Arduino Nano.

I found [this library](https://github.com/kehribar/nrf24L01_plus). It's the only one I found which is written in C. I understand most of the functions when they are explained but I don't understand how to compile the code.

I'm used to do this with CodeBlocks but here I have to use gcc commands, I guess. That's what I have done. But I've tried to compile any `.c` file I found and each time `avr/io.h` or `undefined reference to 'nrf24_miso_digitalRead, undefined refernec to 'nrf24_sck_digitalWrite` was returned.

Comment: You forgot to link in the libraries?

Comment: Yes, sorry but it seems that someone has done it for me. (The editing system is amazing :o)